# Translation doesn't work with Anonymous user at symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have symfony 2.3 and I configured the translation for i18n purpose, putting the _locale in url, and it works well for authenticated users but not for anonymous user, for the anonymous user always give me the default locale, at the profiler the locale appears well but It don't load the proper translation.

Pd: I'm using FOSUserBundle

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the session has been started for the anonymous user. in your controller check with:

```
$this->container->get('session')->isStarted()
```

**start session**

```
$this->container->get('session')->start();
```

If the session is started correctly, verify the locale has been set.

using `$this->get()` alias for `$this->container->get()` in further examples.

**get the locale**

```
$this->get('session')->get('_locale');
```

otherwise **set the locale**

```
$this->get('session')->set('_locale', 'en_US');
```

Comment: It returns true for both (anonymous and registered)

Comment: I have already tried at the top of my controller, the session is empty  at both chases (anonymous and logged user)